# How can I change the subtitle language in Blues and bullets on my Playstation 4?

Tags: ps4, blues-and-bullets

So I saw in the end, on the credits the game is localized to my language (Hungarian), but I dosen't find any way for I can change language.
Steam version also have Hungarian subtitles, I'm almost sure, also can be found in here, but I just can't figured out where is the change language settings, I looked all option what I have in my console.
Please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried changing the PS4's system language to Hungarian? If there is no ingame option, games usually automatically use the language the PS4 is set to.

Comment: Ps4 dosen't support hungarian language, only place where I can sett to hungarian is there on the keyboard. And I already setted to Hungary.